# Select Mysql Query inside echo of another query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I would like to know how I can realizes query selection inside echo of already processed query.

This is my firs Mysql Query

```
    SELECT * FROM cursos_modulos
    foreach($result as $row)
        {
$id = $row['id'];
echo"
```

Here where the echo goes I have to make the other query which is:

```
SELECT COUNT(users.userID) 
FROM users
INNER JOIN subscriptions
ON users.userID = subscriptions.user_id
WHERE subscriptions.curso_id = $id
```

and at the end to put the result of this query

```
foreach($result as $rowc)
.$rowc[0]."};
```

Any help how I can achive this goal will be very welcome. Question is simple. First Select Selects the Cours with it's unique ID. which ID have to be used in the second, third and else... queries. Which queries are like the second one. So First Select Course and then Select different parameters from this course based on this ID. at the end dump results of each of the selections with different indications"

Comment: Couldn't you use another JOIN and add `cursos_modulos` to the COUNT query?

Comment: First I have to select the Course which have unique ID, based on this ID, the next query will be realized with the parameter WHERE = $id

Comment: This could be handled fully with sql

Comment: How can be handled in this case?

Comment: You don't put the query inside the echo. You just do another query, and do a loop to print out the results of that query. But the best way is to combine the two queries into a join.

Comment: this is a great example of how not to use php. Do you want to modify the question so mysql does the heavy lifting in a join? If so show some table details. Granted, I said nothing new here :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it all in one query:

```
SELECT c.*, count(s.curso_id) as count
FROM cursos_modulos AS c
LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.curso_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = s.user_id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is needed to get `0` for the count if there are no matching rows in `subscriptions`.

To include a second count of approved subscriptions:

```
SELECT c.*, count(s.curso_id) as count, SUM(IF(s.approved = 'approved', 1, 0)) AS count_approved
FROM cursos_modulos AS c
LEFT JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.curso_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = s.user_id
```

Comment: Barmer one last question in case If I have to add one more count_aproved(a.curso_id)  -  WHERE subscriptions.curso_id = $id AND subscriptions.status = 'aproved'  is it will be possible with the query in this state ?

Comment: Put `AND s.status = 'approved'` in the first `ON` line.

Comment: that works just fine in case if the condition is AND in only one count result. what I try to achieve is to make a Third Select, and get another for example count_aproved result in the array. Which will comes from exactly the same Select command but will have this AND condition.

Comment: so let;s say: SELECT c.*, count(s.curso_id) as count,  count_aproved(a.curso_id) as count

Comment: What is `count_approved()`? That's not a MySQL function.

Comment: Maybe what you mean is `SUM(IF(s.status = 1, 1, 0)) AS count_approved`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88237/discussion-between-john-siniger-and-barmar).